# How can I integrate in html pages 2 different CSS styles for 2 diferent images?

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

Can anyone help me?

How can I integrate in html pages 2 different CSS styles for 2 diferent images, both being separated vertically by a space?

See the paintings below. They have different sizes, different styles.

[image]

Comment: apply different classes to the image, use `nth-child` or `nth-of-type` selector. What is the issue you stuck with?

Comment: can you please show me the html/css code as an answer? I cannot understand whay you mean..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this. You may change the dimensions anytime

```
.img, .firstImage, .secondImage {
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    width: 200px;
}

.firstImage {
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 150px;
}

.secondImage {
    float:right;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 120px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A friend write for me this code, a good answer:

**HTML**

```
<div id="img1"><img src=logo.png"></div>
<div id="img2"><img src=logo2.png"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#img1{border-style :solid;
border-color:red;}

#img2{border-style :solid;
border-color:blue;
margin-top:20px;}
```

SOURCE: [HERE](https://codepen.io/miki07/pen/JjONWaQ)